# Extending limesurvey's controls in each entry

Tags: limesurvey

I want to extend limesurvey with a custom control created with some graphical libraries (e.g. go.js), so the user can choose his answer from a tree. The title says "entry" instead of "question" because that word is not allowed in the title.

I already read:
https://manual.limesurvey.org/Plugins
https://manual.limesurvey.org/Plugin_events
http://codelogic.ws/2015/12/07/limesurvey-plug-in-hello-world/

But I couldn't find detailed info about the underlying possibilities. Do you know some book? tutorial? manual? demo? etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need plugin event here, you can do it in javascript. LimeSUrvey include jquery, then it's easy.

See this example : http://demonstration.sondages.pro/21764

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        //$('#question{QID} .survey-question-answer ').hide(); //uncomment to hide radio button

 $("path").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id') != "selected")
                {
                        $("[name={SGQ}]").filter("[value='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").attr("checked",true);
   $("#selected").css('fill',$(this).css('fill'));
                }
  else
                {
   $("#selected").css('fill','none');
                        $("[name={SGQ}]").attr("checked",false);
                }
 });
});
</script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="150" height="150" style="margin-left:25px">
  <path
     d="M 73.21875,0.03125 A 74.999999,74.999999 0 0 0 37.5,10.0625 l 18.75,32.5 a 37.5,37.5 0 0 1 37.5,-0.03125 L 112.5,10.0625 A 74.999999,74.999999 0 0 0 73.21875,0.03125 z"
     id="C1"
     style="fill:#008000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;cursor:pointer" />
  <path
     d="M 112.5,10.0625 93.75,42.53125 A 37.5,37.5 0 0 1 112.5,75 L 150,75 A 74.999999,74.999999 0 0 0 112.5,10.0625 z"
     id="C2"
     style="fill:#ffff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;cursor:pointer" />
  <path
     d="m 112.5,75 a 37.5,37.5 0 0 1 -18.75,32.4375 l 18.75,32.5 A 74.999999,74.999999 0 0 0 150,75 l -37.5,0 z"
     id="C3"
     style="fill:#ff8000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;cursor:pointer" />
  <path
     d="m 93.75,107.4375 a 37.5,37.5 0 0 1 -37.5,0.0312 L 37.5,139.9375 a 74.999999,74.999999 0 0 0 75,0 l -18.75,-32.5 z"
     id="C4"
     style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;cursor:pointer" />
  <path
     d="m 0,75 a 74.999999,74.999999 0 0 0 37.5,64.9375 L 56.25,107.46875 A 37.5,37.5 0 0 1 37.5,75 L 0,75 z"
     id="C5"
     style="fill:#800080;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;cursor:pointer" />
  <path
     d="M 37.5,10.0625 A 74.999999,74.999999 0 0 0 0,75 l 37.5,0 A 37.5,37.5 0 0 1 56.25,42.5625 l -18.75,-32.5 z"
     id="C6"
     style="fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;cursor:pointer" />
  <path
     d="m -182.40128,-1.5888613 a 48.619156,48.619156 0 1 1 -97.23831,0 48.619156,48.619156 0 1 1 97.23831,0 z"
     transform="matrix(0.23653228,0,0,0.23653228,129.64379,75.375816)"
     id="selected"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:8.45550537;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none" />
</svg>
```

For plugin developement : have some example of code : https://framagit.org/groups/SondagePro-LimeSurvey-plugin

To hack answer part and do the same without touch of question text, just using a specific class : see https://framagit.org/SondagePro-LimeSurvey-plugin/radioToStarRating this one